# Sabre CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ

Tags: xml, api, soap, sabre

I'm integrating the sabre web services and I want to use **CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ** instead of *EnhancedAirBookRQ* and *PassengerDetailsRQ* so I made the following request (including AirBook, 
 AirPrice, PostProcessing, (TravelItineraryAddInfo-to add customer information))

```
    <CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2" haltOnAirPriceError="false" targetCity="AAAA">
    <AirBook>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NO" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NN" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="US" />  
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
          <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2018-02-15T08:00:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-02-15T09:00:00" FlightNumber="651" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="Y" Status="NN">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHE" />
            <MarketingAirline Code="PK" FlightNumber="651" />
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" />
          </FlightSegment>
          <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2018-02-20T06:00:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-02-20T07:00:00" FlightNumber="650" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="Y" Status="NN">
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="ISB" />
            <MarketingAirline Code="PK" FlightNumber="650" />
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="LHE" />
          </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
    </AirBook>
    <AirPrice>
         <PriceRequestInformation>
            <OptionalQualifiers>
                <PricingQualifiers>
                     <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                     <PassengerType Code="CNN" Quantity="1"/>
                     <PassengerType Code="INF" Quantity="1"/>
                </PricingQualifiers>
            </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>
    </AirPrice>
    <TravelItineraryAddInfo> 
        <AgencyInfo> 
            <Address> 
                <AddressLine>My Company</AddressLine> 
                <CityName>Dubai</CityName> 
                <CountryCode>PK</CountryCode> 
                <PostalCode>00000</PostalCode> 
                <StateCountyProv StateCode="DX"/> 
                <StreetNmbr>SZ Road</StreetNmbr> 
            </Address>
            <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW"/> 
        </AgencyInfo> 
            <CustomerInfo> 
                <ContactNumbers> 
                    <ContactNumber LocationCode="LHE" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="971-589-697242" PhoneUseType="A"/> 
                </ContactNumbers> 
                <Email Address="darabjavaid@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1"/> 
                <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT" > 
                    <GivenName>ADULT</GivenName> 
                    <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <PersonName NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="CNN"  > 
                    <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName> 
                    <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
                </PersonName>
                <PersonName NameNumber="3.1" Infant="true" PassengerType="INF" > 
                    <GivenName>INFANT</GivenName> 
                    <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
                </PersonName>
            </CustomerInfo> 
    </TravelItineraryAddInfo>
    <PostProcessing RedisplayReservation="true" > 
        <EndTransactionRQ> 
            <EndTransaction Ind="true"/> 
            <Source ReceivedFrom=" TESTING"/> 
        </EndTransactionRQ>
    </PostProcessing> 
    </CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ>
```

But when I post this request, the response returned said **Invalid content was found starting with element 'TravelItineraryAddInfo'**:

```
<soap-env:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap-env:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Message validation failed. Errors: [cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'TravelItineraryAddInfo'. One of '{"http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":AirTax, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":MiscSegment, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":SpecialReqDetails, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":PostProcessing}' is expected.cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'EndTransactionRQ'. One of '{"http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":ARUNK, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":QueuePlace, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":EndTransaction}' is expected.]</faultstring>
        <detail>
            <ApplicationResults xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/STL_Payload/v02_01" status="NotProcessed">
                <Error type="Validation" timeStamp="2018-02-06T02:47:20.366-06:00">
                    <SystemSpecificResults>
                        <Message code="ERR.SP.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED">Message validation failed. Errors: [cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'TravelItineraryAddInfo'. One of '{"http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":AirTax, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":MiscSegment, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":SpecialReqDetails, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":PostProcessing}' is expected.cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'EndTransactionRQ'. One of '{"http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":ARUNK, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":QueuePlace, "http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2":EndTransaction}' is expected.]</Message>
                    </SystemSpecificResults>
                </Error>
            </ApplicationResults>
        </detail>
    </soap-env:Fault>
```

1. kindly tell me what parameter I'm missing or what should I do to add customer information in the **CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ** too.
2. please verify if this request is valid or should I need to add more information to make it right.
   Thanks.
3. Pleae tell me where I can find the whole documentation of *CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I am not sure what you mean by "to add customer information", you are adding an adult, child and infant in the node `CustomerInfo`.
2. The request you've pasted is not valid, because the order of elements is a bit different and you have some extra stuff.
   a. `TravelItineraryAddInfo` should be first, before `AirBook`.
   b. Inside `PostProcessing`, you should have `EndTransaction` and not `EndTransactionRQ`.
   c. `<EndTransaction Ind="true"/>` is not expected, as the service creates the PNR by default.
3. Link: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/resources

XML with corrected elements, you will start having other errors, the `targetCity` element containg an invalid PCC.

```
<CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/reservation/v2" haltOnAirPriceError="false" targetCity="AAAA">
    <TravelItineraryAddInfo> 
        <AgencyInfo> 
            <Address> 
                <AddressLine>My Company</AddressLine> 
                <CityName>Dubai</CityName> 
                <CountryCode>PK</CountryCode> 
                <PostalCode>00000</PostalCode> 
                <StateCountyProv StateCode="DX"/> 
                <StreetNmbr>SZ Road</StreetNmbr> 
            </Address>
            <Ticketing TicketType="7TAW"/> 
        </AgencyInfo> 
        <CustomerInfo> 
            <ContactNumbers> 
                <ContactNumber LocationCode="LHE" NameNumber="1.1" Phone="971-589-697242" PhoneUseType="A"/> 
            </ContactNumbers> 
            <Email Address="darabjavaid@gmail.com" NameNumber="1.1"/> 
            <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT" > 
                <GivenName>ADULT</GivenName> 
                <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName NameNumber="2.1" PassengerType="CNN"  > 
                <GivenName>CHILD</GivenName> 
                <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
            </PersonName>
            <PersonName NameNumber="3.1" Infant="true" PassengerType="INF" > 
                <GivenName>INFANT</GivenName> 
                <Surname>KHAN</Surname>
            </PersonName>
        </CustomerInfo> 
    </TravelItineraryAddInfo>
    <AirBook>
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NO" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="NN" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="UC" />
        <HaltOnStatus Code="US" />  
        <OriginDestinationInformation>
            <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2018-02-15T08:00:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-02-15T09:00:00" FlightNumber="651" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="Y" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHE" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="PK" FlightNumber="651" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="ISB" />
            </FlightSegment>
            <FlightSegment DepartureDateTime="2018-02-20T06:00:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-02-20T07:00:00" FlightNumber="650" NumberInParty="2" ResBookDesigCode="Y" Status="NN">
                <DestinationLocation LocationCode="ISB" />
                <MarketingAirline Code="PK" FlightNumber="650" />
                <OriginLocation LocationCode="LHE" />
            </FlightSegment>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
    </AirBook>
    <AirPrice>
        <PriceRequestInformation>
            <OptionalQualifiers>
                <PricingQualifiers>
                    <PassengerType Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                    <PassengerType Code="CNN" Quantity="1"/>
                    <PassengerType Code="INF" Quantity="1"/>
                </PricingQualifiers>
            </OptionalQualifiers>
        </PriceRequestInformation>
    </AirPrice>
    <PostProcessing RedisplayReservation="true" > 
        <EndTransaction>
            <Source ReceivedFrom=" TESTING"/> 
        </EndTransaction>
    </PostProcessing> 
</CreatePassengerNameRecordRQ>
```